# Upgrading from Ruby on Rails 4.2.7.1 to 5.0.1 -- still tries to use railties 4.2.7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upgrade, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-4-upgrade

I'm creating a website but have accidentally installed Ruby on Rails version 4 instead of version 5 and would like to upgrade to the latest version in order to use a few of the features that are currently missing from the version I have on my system.

I have tried following this guide:

http://railsapps.github.io/updating-rails.html

I installed `rvm` and ran all the preliminaries in order, up until this section:

```
rvm use ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0 --create
gem install rails
rails -v
```

Where I ran into problems. `rvm use ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0 --create` outputs:

```
ruby-2.3.1 - #gemset created /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0
ruby-2.3.1 - #generating rails5.0 wrappers..........
Using /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1 with gemset rails5.0
```

Fine. `Gem install rails` also proceeds without error, installing all 36 gems including, crucially:

```
Fetching: rails-5.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-5.0.1
```

and

```
Fetching: railties-5.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed railties-5.0.1
```

However, when I run `rails -v` directly afterwards, I get:

```
Could not find proper version of railties (4.2.7.1) in any of the sources  
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

When I run `bundle install`, however, the system reverts to rails 4.2.7.1.

Do I need to do something extra to install/link/whatever railties 4.2.7.1,  and to stop the system reverting to the original version of rails? I don't use rails very much so I'm not particularly familiar with the configuration. Perhaps I need to change a config file within my app?

Comment: What's in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: @Iceman Ah ha! I think I've spotted the problem! Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in the Gemfile, which contained old version numbers. I updated to the following:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.0.1'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.13', '< 0.5'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.6'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 3.0.4'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.4.1'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.1', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Then ran `bundle update` followed by `bundle install` and now have Rails 5.0.1. Thanks to Iceman for suggesting looking in the Gemfile!